# How would you punctuate a question with an explanatory sentence?

Tags: american-english, punctuation, questions, editing

I'm trying to write an article, but I am confused about how to punctuate this question:

- How about a birthday gift? A little something to show you care.

Should it rather be punctuated with an em-dash like this:

- How about a birthday gift — a little something to show you care?

Comment: That's an appositive noun phrase, not a sentence.

Comment: How is this about anything but personal style choices?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a somewhat controversial suggestion, but consider the following:

> How about a birthday gift? — a little something to show you care.

While uncommon, an em-dash following a question mark is not unheard of, and is certainly appropriate for both your intended purpose and medium (presumably a somewhat informal web article).

For more on this usage, see, for instance, this [blog post](https://simplewriting.org/em-dash-and-how-to-use-it-correctly/):

> Use an em dash with an exclamation point or question mark, but not with a comma, a colon, or a semi-colon...

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a sentence, as tchrist mentioned its an appositive noun phrase, it can be considered Dialogue, thus how its punctuated depends on how its said.

"How about a birthday gift? A little something to show you care." This means the speaker at hand, asked a question first, then made a statement after.

"How about a birthday gift - a little something to show you care?" This means the speaker at hand is saying both of the dialogue in a question.

Comment: How would these two pieces of dialogue actually be pronounced differently?